# What do you think of the idea of measuring macroscopic Special Relativistic-kinematic time dilation by placing atomic clocks onto moving dollies?

Tags: special-relativity, atomic-physics, time, time-dilation, relative-motion

We first attempt to synchronize two stationary clocks placed apart, and we assume we succeed using the Einstein synchronization convention.

Then, we run a third clock along a dolly at a constant speed. This third clock brushes past one clock, and syncs with it, and then brushes past the other clock, where the time difference can be compared.

By doing so, we can minimize gravitational effects on time dilation, isolating just the macroscopic Special Relativistic-kinematic time dilation.

And we can also have well-controlled moving velocity conditions for the atomic clocks.

Setting the entire atomic clock into motion will produce macroscopic time dilation, demonstrating a macroscopic effect of Special Relativity.

Some researchers have done a microscopic version by setting the individual atoms in an atomic clock into motion. This is macroscopic as the entire big bulky clock would be set into motion.

I don't think such an experiment has been conducted before, as experiments like Hafele-Keating don't have the above criteria.

Comment: In what way does an **atomic** clock demonstrate a macroscopic effect and a Mossbauer rotor doesn’t? What makes a macroscopic effect distinct from a microscopic one? Please clarify in the question itself.

Comment: ok, I've clarified in the question. I also didn't say that a Mossbauer rotor doesn't.

So, some researchers have done a microscopic version by setting the individual atoms in an atomic clock into motion. This one would be macroscopic as the entire big bulky clock would be set into motion.

Comment: Sounds impractical. How fast is this dolly? At 30 m/s ($\approx c×10^{-7}$) the Lorentz factor is $\gamma\approx1+5×10^{-15}$, which would be challenging to measure accurately. (Sure, we have experimental clocks that can measure smaller intervals than a femtosecond, but they probably don't perform so well on a dolly hurtling along at 108 km/h). If we go up to 30 km/s (around Earth's orbital speed) we get $\gamma\approx1+5×10^{-9}$, which isn't too hard to measure, but of course it's a little difficult to move a dolly at that speed on the Earth's surface. ;)

Comment: hmmm, I was inspired by this experiment, "Optical Clocks and Relativity"

(https://sci-hub.do/10.1126/science.1192720)

they were able to measure something at low speeds, i wonder how well it would translate to this

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. They have already done it. With planes.

[Hafele–Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment).

Comment: Sorry, in my description, I mentioned: "By doing so, we can minimize gravitational effects on time dilation, isolating just the macroscopic Special Relativistic-kinematic time dilation.

And we can also have well-controlled moving velocity conditions for the atomic clocks."

Some additional controls to the experiment.

Comment: How would you minimise GR effects by still being on the surface of the Earth?

Comment: Say we're comparing a moving clock on a dolly to a stationary clock. 

As they're both in the same location at the same height, the gravitational differences between the two clocks would be minimized.

So its all about the differences between the clocks

Comment: Should at least provide a summary of this experiment.

Comment: What is the "macroscopic" time dilation? Is there a microscopic one too?

Comment: ok, adding it in the description now

Comment: Some researchers did a microscopic version by setting the individual atoms in an atomic clock into motion. This is macroscopic as the entire big bulky clock would be set into motion.

Answer (score 1):

> Some researchers have done a microscopic version by setting the individual atoms in an atomic clock into motion. This is macroscopic as the entire big bulky clock would be set into motion.

This distinction between macroscopic and microscopic is not terribly meaningful in general, but it is particularly meaningless in the context of atomic clocks. An atomic clock is called an atomic clock precisely because the frequency standard used is some specific atomic transition, i.e. microscopic. So the actual clock part of an atomic clock, the frequency standard, is always microscopic. The macroscopic object is not the frequency standard itself, but just the housing.

So, in any sense in which an atomic clock qualifies as "macroscopic", so would a Mossbauer rotor. With a Mossbauer rotor the absorption frequency is also determined at the atomic level, and the moving equipment just serves to hold the frequency standard. Mossbauer rotor experiments have already demonstrated "macroscopic" time dilation several decades ago. A Mossbauer rotor may even have more of a claim of being "macroscopic" because the defining property of no recoil in a Mossbauer absorber depends strongly on the atom being part of a larger solid structure.

> What do you think of the idea of measuring macroscopic Special Relativistic-kinematic time dilation by placing atomic clocks onto moving dollies?

Although I think it is not particularly meaningful, I am sure that it will be done. It will not be the first macroscopic measurement of time dilation, but it would be a measurement of macroscopic time dilation with a new technology. Such experiments usually get performed as a publicity stunt if nothing else.

In 2018, Origlia, et al. (Phys. Rev. A.) reported a portable optical atomic clock with fractional uncertainty of $2 \ 10^{-17}$. At that level you would be sensitive to velocity based time dilation effects at about 1.9 m/s and gravitational based time dilation effects at about 18 cm. So it would be quite feasible to keep a clock at a constant velocity at those speeds and at a constant height within that tolerance. Since it is feasible, I am sure that it will be done at some point.

Comment: while the frequency standard is always microscopic, i think a macroscopic causation, like setting the entire bulky atomic clock into motion, might be a more crystallized demonstration of how the effect is due to nothing but relative motion, especially to a lay audience, what do you think

Comment: @tnomvc yes, that is more or less what I meant by “publicity stunt”. It is not something that the scientific community would anticipate being informative. But it would give a good press release

Comment: ok i see.

I think that considering that regard, it also has some good value.